# Why is onReceive not being called from android widget?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, android-widget

I do not understand why my onReceive is not being called. I have set up my intent in my onUpdate function like this:

```
     @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
        override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray, widgetData: SharedPreferences) {
    
    
    
                appWidgetIds.forEach { widgetId ->
    
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.home_widget).apply {
    
    
    //            Log.i("LOGSSSSSSS", "on update FIRED");
    //            val pendingIntentWithData = HomeWidgetLaunchIntent.getActivity(
    //                context,
    //                MainActivity::class.java,
    //            )
    //
    //            setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetContainer, pendingIntentWithData);
    
    
               val HOME_WIDGET_BACKGROUND_ACTION = "es.antonborri.home_widget.action.BACKGROUND"
    
                val intentSync = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                intentSync.action =
                    HOME_WIDGET_BACKGROUND_ACTION//You need to specify the action for the intent. Right now that intent is doing nothing for there is no action to be broadcasted.
    
    
                val pendingSync = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    widgetId,
                    intentSync,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
                ) //You need to specify a proper flag for the intent. Or else the intent will become deleted.
    
                 setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.logo, pendingSync)
...

}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml has

```
      <receiver android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundReceiver" android:exported="true">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.action.BACKGROUND" />
               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>
```

And my onReceive

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent)
    val extras: Bundle? = intent.extras
    val strAction = intent.action
    Log.i("LOGSSSSSSS", "Receiver ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED fired");

    if (intent.getAction() == "es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundReceiver") {
        Log.i("LOGSSSSSSS", "YESSSS");
    }
  
}
```

Yet nothing is being logged when I tap on the image? Please tell me where I went wrong, I have spent way too much time on this. Thanks.

Comment: `Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)` – That should be `HomeWidgetBackgroundReceiver::class.java` instead, since that's the target of the broadcast, not `MainActivity`.

Comment: I should also mention that the action you're setting does not match the action you're checking for, so you're not gonna see that log, as is. Also, you don't need the `<intent-filter>` in the manifest, since you're specifying the target class on the `Intent`.